# ionic useHistory push without transition

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to navigate throught page with `useHistory`

```
history.push(`/maintabs/${track?.raceId}/${track?.id}/edition/${poiID}`, {})
```

What I want to do is to navigate without a transition.

Is there a way to achieve this (like the  component and his `routerDirection` props ?)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
 <IonItem button routerLink="/home">
      <IonLabel>Go to HomePage</IonLabel>
 </IonItem>
```

You can try with or without `button` !